# How often /etc/shadow file is backed up?

Tags: linux, passwords, filesystems

From man 5 shadow:

> /etc/shadow-
>
> ```
>        Backup file for /etc/shadow.
>
>        Note that this file is used by the tools of the shadow toolsuite,
>        but not by all user and password management tools.
> ```

What I would like to know is, when this file is backed up?
Is there a configuration file in which change the frequency of, or even disable, this backups?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Hi @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp, where should I ask this kind of questions? Can I export it?

Comment: Most likely on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience the files are backed up whenever they are modified. Thus when a user executes passwd to change his/her own password the /old/ version of the shadow file is moved to **/etc/shadow-** and the new version is written to **/etc/shadow**, same applies with **/etc/gshadow** and **/etc/gshadow-** but its not common to assign passwords to groups nowadays.

http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow

http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd

From shadow(5):

> #### Files
>
> - **/etc/passwd**
>
>   *User account information.*
> - **/etc/shadow**
>
>   *Secure user account information.*
> - **/etc/shadow-**
>
>   *Backup file for /etc/shadow.*
>
> Note that this file is used by the tools of the shadow toolsuite, but not by all user and password management tools.